# I cannot open FTP folder in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, ftp

Thanks for reading this question..
I've made a FTP (file transfer protocol) account on www.1freehosting.com
and some other free sites.
But when I open my FTP server in Window Explorer, I got an error..(error screenshot link : http://goo.gl/9LIy7k )
I also have turn ON FTP server in windows features..
Please help me and get me out of this problem.

I have :-

PC

Windows 8.1 pro

64-bit

THANKS for HELP...

Comment: I'm typing everything correct.. I've watch some tutorials on YouTube and I am following there method and I've also try the method which my FTP account hosting site Provide.. But Can't open my server. :( Please help.......This is what I watch in videos :-  ftp://USERNAME@DOMAIN

Comment: Show us the URL you enter to the Windows Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the FTP client that Microsoft provides for Windows systems, it does not support passive FTP only active FTP - see [Active FTP vs. Passive FTP, a Definitive Explanation](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html). You can issue a PASV command using Microsoft's FTP client, but it won't work. With active FTP, your system will connect to an FTP server on port 21 and send commands to the server. The FTP server will then try to connect to your system from port 20 on its side to another port on your system for data transfer, e.g., the source port plus 1 from which your system established the connection to the server's port 21. That usually doesn't work unless you have set up the appropriate firewall rules on your system and in any firewall before your system. E.g., you may also need to set up an appropriate rule in your router. See [NAT and firewall traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#NAT_and_firewall_traversal). The simplest course in such situations is to use an FTP client on your system that supports passive FTP, such as [WinSCP](http://winscp.net). WinSCP also supports [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol), which is built on the Secure Shell (SSH) protocol, make sure you set it to use FTP not SFTP for the connection by selecting "FTP" as the file protocol when you initiate a new session, since the default value is SFTP. If you can connect to the server with an FTP client that supports passive FTP, you won't have to worry about firewall rules on your end. For most people, that is a much easier method to get FTP transfers working.

Also note, if you have created a free account on www.1freehosting.com and other sites where the other site is providing FTP server service, the other side is the "server" and you are the "client" - see [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model). You don't need to turn on any server support on your system when it is to be the client communicating with another system that is functioning as the server.

Comment: The question is about Windows Explorer, not `ftp.exe` command-line client. While the `ftp.exe` client does not suppost the passive mode, the Windows Explorer does.